# How to use javascript to get proximity or ambient light sensor value from mobile device?

Tags: javascript, sensors, light, proximity, ambient

I'm looking for a way to get proximity or ambient light sensor value through javascript for web app development. I know that it's possible on each platform through every native app development.

Comment: For which mobile OS? iOS/Android/WP7?

Answer (score 1):

You can access a device's proximity sensor through the DeviceProximityEvent event. Unfortunately, at the moment only Firefox for desktop and Firefox for Android support the proximity API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceProximityEvent

Answer (score 0):

Something like PhoneGap might be a good bet. Their API: http://docs.phonegap.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

Currently only Firefox supports proximity sensor API.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceProximityEvent